# SQL VM Missing in Azure SQL Databases

Tags: sql, azure

I have an operational SQL VM in Azure. How do I provision Azure to see it under SQL Databases and provide it as an option when creating something like Mobile Services?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not possible.  The SQL Database feature is a service and, while it does run a highly compatible SQL Server environment, it is not the same as the SQL Server you would install on premises, or on a hosted virtual machine.  There is not a way to "register" an existing SQL Server database, either in or outside of Azure, as a SQL Database instance.

If you want to have the Mobile Services system pointing to a SQL Server instance that is NOT a SQL Database I do not believe that is possible either.  You can post a suggestion to the http://www.mygreatwindowsazureidea.com/forums/34192-general-feedback- site.  The product group does monitor this and take it into account during product backlog sessions.

Comment: Actually, using server-side scripts in mobile services, you can write to any data store...

Comment: However - Mike is right in that you cannot swap out Windows Azure SQL Database and swap in SQL Server, from a default operation standpoint...

Comment: @DavidMakogon True, in the node script you can write to anything you can reach, but it is not an option when creating the mobile service at this time. You'd need to store the connection string manually and create the connections on your own.